# 6DOF Localization with stereo camera against RGBD dense point cloud

Tags: localization, navigation, odometry, 3d-slam, stereo-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a point cloud of an environment generated by a Kinect One using rtabmap. I have a stereo camera, and I'm looking for a ROS package capable of performing full 6DOF localization using the stereo camera against this existing point cloud. Although I have found many solutions for stereo SLAM, I am having a hard time finding anything for localization-only using the stereo camera. What I have found seems to only be depth-based. I'm looking for something that could perform this localization based on the full RGBD cloud, and is compatible with Kinetic. Are there any packages that do this? I would like to produce a pose estimate primarily based on the stereo camera, augmented by IMUs and IR rangefinders, and other monocular cameras. Presumably, once I have a stereo localization, I could pass the other sensors through the robot_localization package to get a fused posed estimate. Any suggestions for a stereo localization package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247008/6dof-localization-with-stereo-camera-against-rgbd-dense-point-cloud/) by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you mentionned `rtabmap`, I'll describe what you can already do with it. `rtabmap` can do stereo localization in a map created previously by `rtabmap` (with any other sensors, stereo or rgb-d):

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros stereo_mapping.launch database_path:="~/map_created_with_kinect.db" localization:=true
```

See [stereo_mapping.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/stereo_mapping.launch) for other remapping options (image topics or `frame_id`.). You can also see this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoHandHeldMapping) on stereo mapping with rtabmap.

`rtabmap` will not do stereo/rgbd localization on an arbitrary raw point cloud, only with its database format.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) on 2016-11-02**:
This solution is only localization based on loop closure images, right? It is not localizing against any point cloud or 3D data, but only against the loop closure images and their vectors, right?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-11-03**:
Yes this is against the loop closure images. When a matching image is found, the 6DOF pose of the camera is computed against it (using the 3D keypoints and/or laser scans), so it is localized in the map.